# band gap (or energy gap) relation with discontinuity on spceific heat

Tags: superconductivity

Is change in band gap or energy gap with respect to temperature, reason behind the discontinuity in specific heat data as in case of superconductors?

Comment: The transition from normal to superconducting state is (generally considered) a second order phase transition.

Comment: yeah and so, there is a sudden change in specific heat. but i need a physical understanding of it. but do we see such discontinuity in semiconductor. the answer is no because, the band gap is constant. in case of superconductors, however the band gap is changing, so we find a discontinuity. Now if you can explain to me that way. i would b very thankful. like at critical temperature , energy gap becomes zero.

Comment: Band gaps in semiconductors change with temperature - they are decidedly not constant. In superconductors the point isn't the band gap changing, but the formation of Cooper pairs which changes the electronic heat capacity.